# web worker constructor does not fail even with invalid file path

Tags: javascript, webpack, web-worker

I have this code in a web file bundled with webpack 3:

```
let _worker = new Worker("x.js")
_worker.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
    resolve(event.data as any)
});
```

The worker creation always succeeds, no matter what path I pass to the constructor. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

> How is this possible?

Because it's *asynchronous*. You wouldn't want your main JavaScript thread to sit around, blocked, waiting for the browser to fetch the script file from the server. So it's done asynchronously.

If you listen for the worker's `error` event, you'll receive it for a worker created using an invalid path.

This is covered [in the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/workers/#dedicated-workers-and-the-worker-interface) in the list of steps labelled *"When the Worker(scriptURL) constructor is invoked, the user agent must run the following steps:"* which doesn't list anything about the browser fetching the URL.

The last step in that is [run a worker](https://www.w3.org/TR/workers/#run-a-worker), which starts like this:

> 1. Create a separate parallel execution environment (i.e. a separate thread or process or equivalent construct), and run the rest of these steps in that context.
>
> ...
>
> 4. Let request be a new request whose url is url...
> 5. Let response be the result of fetching request.
> 6. If response response's status is an ok status...
>
>    Otherwise, then for each Worker or SharedWorker object associated with worker global scope, queue a task to fire a simple event named `error` at that object. Abort these steps.

Comment: But I used to get an error in the browser console whenever the path was invalid (something like: path xxx not found"); this does not happen now

Comment: @prmph: Is your server set to provide a default response to invalid URLs? If I do `new Worker("fooalskdjflaskdf.js").onerror = function(e) { console.log("failed", e); };` here on SO, I get the error from the web worker and then a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` because SO responds with a page (not a 404 as it should). But if I do it on a site where the server responds with 404, I get an error in the console. Also note that most consoles have filtering options, you may have turned one on by mistake. Regardless, if the response isn't valid JavaScript, you'll get the worker error.

Comment: So how does one create a worker and proceed only after ensuring it has been properly created? Can you post a short snippet illustrating this?

Comment: @prmph: I'd do it by handling the `error` event and the `message` event, and having the worker send a message when it's loaded and initialized. You might throw in a timeout for good measure, but I'd expect either `error` or the worker to run (and so if it runs it can send the message).